# Is there any European country considering banning or already banned research funding from China?

Tags: china, europe

https://www.thestar.com/politics/federal/canada-to-ban-funding-for-research-linked-to-foreign-universities-labs-that-pose-risk-to/article_c1ba9382-b3f6-11ee-a836-5fdd9a639283.html

> Canada is banning federal funding for research done in affiliation
> with, or with funding from, more than 100 Chinese, Iranian and Russian
> universities and labs that it deems a risk to national security.
>
> The policy unveiled Tuesday applies to research in areas deemed to be
> "sensitive" to national security, and is expected to apply to "tens of
> thousands" of research grant applications, according to government
> officials. The announcement includes two lists: one of the banned
> entities, and one of the sensitive research areas, which include
> advanced energy, weapons, artificial intelligence, robotics and life
> science technology.

> In line with the ongoing discussions on the Joint Roadmap, on 22 April
> 2022, the EU and China signed an Administrative Arrangement for the
> period 2021-2024 to set up a Co-funding Mechanism that will support
> collaborative research projects under the two agreed flagship
> initiatives on Food, Agriculture and Biotechnology (FAB) and on
> Climate Change and Biodiversity (CCB). Through the Co-funding
> Mechanism, Chinese entities participating in the projects under the
> flagship topics will be funded by the Ministry of Science and
> Technology of the People’s Republic of China.

https://research-and-innovation.ec.europa.eu/strategy/strategy-2020-2024/europe-world/international-cooperation/bilateral-cooperation-science-and-technology-agreements-non-eu-countries/china_en

Is there any European country considering banning or already banned research funding from China? I know there's scrutiny for everything that come from China in Europe, but I am wondering if any European country went ahead and put restriction on Chinese scientific collaboration. However, it seems that EU does collaborate with China and accepts funding from Chinese sources, but I couldn't find if there are sensitive areas where this is prohibited.

Comment: Note that the law is about both 'with and funding from' and 'in affilitation with'. Getting funding from these countries for research conducted in Europe or North America is extremely rare but collaberations with researchers from these countries are quite common in some academic fields.

Comment: *banned research funding from China?* Do you instead mean **for** China (universities and labs)?